# Efficiently computing GCDs in $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algorithms

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ is a PID; hence any two elements have a GCD. How you would compute their GCD?

In a Euclidean domain, you would use the Euclidean algorithm. But $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ is not Euclidean.

If you knew prime factorizations of the two elements, you could immediately compute the GCD. But surely factoring in $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ is at least as hard as factoring in $\mathbb{Z}$. At least for now, we do not know how to do this efficiently.

So, is there an efficient algorithm to compute GCD?

(You may use the *de facto* interpretation of "efficient" as "polynomial time".)

Comment: It is possible to use the Dedekind-Hasse criterion for devising an algorithm; see  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1147.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer, just trying to draw attention to your question.

Humans such as yourself generally find  factorization in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2}\right]$ to be more difficult than factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$ because $\mathbb{Z}$ is familiar and $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2}\right]$ is unfamiliar.

So if I was bedraggled by human failings, I would see about how to leverage my familiarity with one to my advantage in the other. The way is with norms.

If the norms of two numbers in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2}\right]$ are coprime, then the two numbers must be coprime as well. Example: $$N\left( \frac{3 + \sqrt{-19}}{2} \right) = 7$$ and $$N\left( \frac{9 + \sqrt{-19}}{2} \right) = 25,$$ so since $\gcd(7, 25) = 1$, this must mean that $$\gcd\left( \frac{3 + \sqrt{-19}}{2},  \frac{9 + \sqrt{-19}}{2} \right) = 1$$ as well.

But if the norms do have a common divisor, then  it's a little more difficult, for humans anyway. Example: $$\gcd\left( \frac{3 + \sqrt{-19}}{2},  11 + \sqrt{-19} \right) = ???$$

Answer (score 1):

The last time I wanted to do this, I used the $O(n^2)$ algorithm  described in [Agarwal and Frandsen](http://cs.au.dk/~gudmund/Documents/38870030.pdf).  I think I recall that your specific case is easier because $-19 < 0$.